# CSS nest combinators

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following code somewhere:

```
<div>
    <h1></h1>
</div>
<a></a>
```

And additional code elsewhere:

```
<div>
    <h1 class="specialClass"></h1>
</div>
<a></a>
```

I would like to write CSS that only selects the second anchor tag. Is this doable? My original guess was to do a selector like the following:

```
div > h1.specialClass ~ a
```

But that does not work. How do I nest the combinators to get that/is that even possible in current css?

Comment: It can't (yet) be done as there is no parent selector. You'd need JavaScript.

Comment: Bah that's what I was afraid of. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to select the second anchor tag or the second tag if it's an anchor?

Answer (score -1):

If both tags are children of the same parent then you can use [the `:nth-of-type()` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp):

```
a:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: red;
}
```